# How to make inter container calls within a pod in Elastic Kubernetes Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, deployment, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I have a pod which contains 4 containers A, B, C and D. A communicates with B and C. B and C communicate with D. Each container runs on a different port. Let's assume container A makes calls to container B like https://XYZ:8000/api/getList and similarly B and C send request to D as https://XYZ:9000/api/v1/getProduct. In docker in place of XYZ I was using localhost. When deploying to Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS) I have a problem that what to replace localhost with as both localhost and 127.0.0.1 are giving connection refused.

The YAML file I am using is :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: app-deployment
    labels:
        app: app-one
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: app-one
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: app-one
      spec:
        containers:
          - name : A
            image: imageA:latest
            ports:
              - name: port1
                containerPort: 3000
            envFrom:
              - secretRef:
                  name: dev-secrets-A
          - name : B
            image: imageB:latest
            ports:
              - name: port2
                containerPort: 8000
            envFrom:
              - secretRef:
                  name: dev-secrets-B
          - name : C
            image: imageC:latest
            ports:
              - name: port3
                containerPort: 8080
            envFrom:
              - secretRef:
                  name: dev-secrets-C
          - name : D
            image: imageD:latest
            ports:
              - name: port4
                containerPort: 9000
            envFrom:
              - secretRef:
                  name: dev-secrets-D
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: app-one
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      name: service-port-1
      targetPort: 3000
    - port: 8000
      name: service-port-2
      targetPort: 8000
    - port: 8080
      name: service-port-3
      targetPort: 8080
    - port: 9000
      name: service-port-4
      targetPort: 9000
```

I am critically confused as tutorials don't specify what needs to be done exactly. One tutorial explained that localhost should work.
One tutorial was saying to put each container in different pod and communicate through services and the example they gave was nothing. If this works do I have to make different cluster for different pods? Or all the pods can be deployed to same cluster on EKS.
I also tried using "service-name.default.svc.cluster.local" in place of localhost but this also didn't work.

What's the issue? Does it has to something with target port or https/http or other?
Please give me the answer!!! Please

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use internal pods and services names [to resolve them](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).

I think you also have typo in your example, port is right after hostname : https://XYZ:8000/api/getList

Also, unless everything is exposed in https internally, which isn't the default for me, then you should use http and not http**s**.

Comment: There it is written that "In summary, a pod in the test namespace can successfully resolve either data.prod or data.prod.svc.cluster.local", so the app-service.default.svc.cluster.local should be resolved for my case but it is not resolving.

Comment: Make sure that you service is in the default namespace. Also, I usually like to ssh to a pod to troubleshoot name resolution issues with curl for example. Can you resolve the 'kubernetes' and or 'kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local' dns name from a pod to get the api endpoint? if not, you have a dns specific config or issue.

Comment: how to resolve this dns issue

Comment: This doc is the best way to start dns troubleshooting with k8s: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/